# Complete list of publications of Rebecca Barlow

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, biographical-details, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Rebecca Barlow is the discoverer of an interesting [surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barlow_surface) in algebraic geometry. Is anybody aware of a full list of her contributions? Has she continued working in mathematics in the 21st century?

Comment: I am not sure if it is already historical.

Comment: The said surface is older than me so pretty historical from my perspective.

Comment: Well, it is then border case :-)

Answer (score 3):

Math Sci Net lists 6 publications, dating from 1984-1999.